# How to test the compliance of the sample with the given distribution by the Chi-square criterion?

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy.stats

Programming language - Python

I generate a sample like this, using the Numpy library, the approximate size is 1 million.

```
uniformSample = UniformSample(1000000)
uniformSample.generate()

def generate(self, a=0.0, b=1.0):
        self.left = a
        self.right = b
        self.sample = [np.random.uniform(low=self.left, high=self.right) for _ in range(self.size)]
```

I have various sample characteristics such as mean, variance, standard deviation and others.
I need to **check that the given sample corresponds to one or another type of distribution** (there are 8 types in my case). You need to check this **using the chi-square tes**t. Dear mathematicians and programmers, can you please help me to check the conformity of the sample to any distribution in the most elegant and simple way possible?

**Using built-in functions and libraries in Python is welcome!**

**Code examples in response to my question is welcome!**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kstest.html) to test if a given data set could come from a given distribtuion. There is a `scipy` function `scipy.stats.kstest` that does this.

You don't say what distribution you are testing against, but for example, you could do something like

```
statistic, pvalue = scipy.stats.kstest(uniformSample.generate(), "norm")
```

To test against a Gaussian distribution. The `pvalue` returned is the probability that the data could come from the passed distribution (in this case the p-value should be extremely small).